# First project from github will not compile: SqlServerSpatial140.dll not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I have a functioning C# WinForms project that I have uploaded to GitHub from my office PC.

This is my first time trying to setup a shared workspace.

I have cloned my GitHub repository to my home computer where i have an identical installation of Visual Studio.  I can open and edit the project files but cannot compile it.

I get two copies of the following errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Dispatcher  E:\Users\Ross Wise\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Dispatcher\DispatcherMain.cs   1   Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\msvcr120.dll'.  Dispatcher

[image: Missing files error message]

I have been fighting this for two days.

I have modified the .gitiqnore file as suggested by madreflection and JayNaz.
During my next push I saw the four .dll files included as "changed".

I synced my Home system verified that the files are in place; however, the compile still fails.

My Office VS compiles successfully:
[image: Office Compile Succeeds]

But the home system fails- even though the files are present in the same path.
[image: Home Compiler Fails]

Problem is unchanged.

With this small test project I can try recreating it as a new project; but that is not an option with my much larger 'real' project.

Comment: Rough guess here... it looks like the assemblies were excluded when you committed. Your `.gitignore` file probably has rules like `[Xx]64/` and `[Xx]86/`, which would exclude those directories and all files under them.

Comment: Expand the reference node in solution explorer and check whether the mentioned DLLs are there. The `.gitignore` ignores the DLLs by default. You have 2 choices. You can manually add the missing DLL in every time or you just change the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @madreflection,  Thanks for responding. It looked like it was solve the problem- The missing files were uploaded and downloaded to home; but the problem is unchanged.

Comment: @JayNaz Thanks for responding. It looked like it was solve the problem- The missing files were uploaded and downloaded to home; but the problem is unchanged.

Comment: @Ross, Assuming you are now including the dll, the modified date of the dlls doesn't looks right. When did you last compiled this project with successful output

Comment: @Nair You were right the wrong local repository was referenced in my commit- one from an earlier attempt.  When I used the correct one, the local project was able to compile and run. Thank you.

Comment: @madreflection- you and JayNaz provided the correct answer; you were first.  if you want credit please repost as a solution.